# Youtube Iframe API return "ptk" parameter

Tags: youtube

I'm currently getting a 404 at http://www.youtube.com/get_video?noflv=1&video_id=Heyb3xd1qyE&cpn=B7nL0OlmP…3A%2F%2Fpoolside.fm%2F&fmt=135&ptk=SonyPicture_LongForm&autoplay=1&splay=1 when using the youtube iframe api.

Interestingly the video still plays. What i've noticed is the "ptk=SonyPicture_LongForm" parameter. Can anyone shed any light on what the ptk parameter is?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue except my ptk param looks like this:

"ptk=rumblefish_cdbaby"

If I find an answer I'll post back here.

Comment: I found this, not sure how much it helps: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6267